# Is it possible to manage Parental Controls on Mobile Accounts at all?

Tags: osx-server, parental-controls, profile-manager

I am using macOS Sierra on clients and macOS Sierra with Server 5.3.1 on my server. I need to set Parental Controls for a user (or group of). I have created a special Group of users in Server.app, added the specific user to that group, and I have added a Parental Controls Payload to that group in Profile Manager.

I also have enrolled the client Mac as a Device in Profile Manager.

But when the user logs in on the client, all of this is totally ignored. And at the same time, I also cannot set the Parental Controls on the local machine because they are removed when the user logs in on the client as long as the client machine is linked to the server's Open Directory.

How can I manage the Parental Controls (or anything, really) of only that specific *Mobile Account* user (or group of users) on all my Macs?